# Loading a sorted arrry into UITableView only ever shows last entry

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that subscribes to a Notification from the default notification center. In the method defined to handle the notification I create a sorted array that is used in my tableview datasource methods.  THe problem is EVERY cell that the UITableVIew shows contains the last entry of the sorted array, so if the sorted array has A, B, C, I get a table with C,C,C...  I cant figure this out as I use that sorted array and put each object in it in a dictionary as seen below in this line:

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [self.sortedbirthdays objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I then use the keys of that dictionary to add to the cell labels..  I am sure this is a logic error on my part but I just cant see it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
-(void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification

{


[self.birthdays addObject:[notification userInfo]];
NSLog(@" unsorted %@", self.birthdays);


NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name"
                                             ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

self.sortedbirthdays = [self.birthdays sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSLog(@" sorted %@", self.sortedbirthdays);
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Here are my data source methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [self.sortedbirthdays count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


NSDictionary *dict = [self.sortedbirthdays objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {

    NSLog(@"sorted birth day length %d", [self.sortedbirthdays count]);

   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"calling cell for row at indexpath with %@:", dict);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[dict valueForKey:@"date"]];
    UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 8.0, 124, 28)];
    [ dateLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    [ dateLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
    [ dateLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [ dateLabel setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    dateLabel.tag = 1;
     dateLabel.text = dateString;

    // Add Main Label to Content View
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dateLabel];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor randomColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];


}

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you set textLabel under if {}  once time; You should set your textLabel after if {}. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` can return existed cell.

You should do like that

```
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.sortedbirthdays objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {

        NSLog(@"sorted birth day length %d", [self.sortedbirthdays count]);

       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSLog(@"calling cell for row at indexpath with %@:", dict);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[dict valueForKey:@"date"]];
    UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 8.0, 124, 28)];
    [ dateLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    [ dateLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
    [ dateLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [ dateLabel setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    dateLabel.tag = 1;
    dateLabel.text = dateString;

    // Add Main Label to Content View
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dateLabel];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor randomColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
```

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` - method for optimization UITableView, even if you return 100 in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method, actually there is less count of UITableViewCell objects in table view

see **Creating and Configuring a Table View** from apple documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10